# Converting from CharSequence to String in Java

Tags: java, string, casting

Suppose I want to convert a CharSequence to a String in Java.

Which option (1 or 2) is better and why?

```
CharSequence source = "some text";
String someText1 = (String)source; // 1
String someText2 = source.toString(); // 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best option is behind Door #3:

```
String someText = String.valueOf(source);
```

Because that will handle the case where `source` is **null**.

Comment: Just a note, it will "handle" that case by setting the value of `someText` to the string `"null"` - which I personally don't think is very elegant, but at least it's easy to check for (as long as you aren't expecting the CharSequence to have the literal value of `"null"`, which I hope you aren't)

Answer (score 2):

#1 doesn't even work for `CharSequence` implementations other than `String`, so #2 is really your only option.

Comment: Not your only option - `String.value of()` is available and superior.

Comment: Eh, the only difference is that it behaves differently on null, which may or may not be desirable.  I would prefer to throw on null as toString would do.